# What are positioned elements in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I need to search for a solution to some HTML/CSS problems, I often find some answers mentioning "positioned elements". I know it refers to the `position` CSS property, but they don't say which `position` value. If it's absolute, relative, static, etc. So, what are positioned elements?

Comment: “This is called CSS positioning. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.”

Comment: I have searched a lot. My question is not about what each value does, but about what they mean when they say "positioned element".

Comment: If you spent more time practicing on those, you could've figured that out. Positioning properties such as `top, right, bottom, left`, and `z-index` especially only work on `positioned elements` fyi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is
> either relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky. (In other words, it's
> anything except static.)

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: This is pretty clear, exactly the answer I was looking for. Also, if I was you, I would mention in your answer that static is the default position value when no position is set, just to make it more clear to people that may end up here. Great answer anyway.